# NS Notification Observer not being removed

Tags: swift, listener

I am working to detect screenshots in my app, here is the problem..

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let mainQueue = OperationQueue.main
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshot,
                                           object: nil,
                                           queue: mainQueue) { notification in
                                           print("SCREENSHOT TAKEN")

        }

    }
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

The observer is working fine, however it doesn't remove the observer, and then I can get tons of repeat listeners. I am attempting to understand the documentation, but I don't understand :/

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe not related but you have to call `super` in both methods.

Comment: Not sure what that does?

Comment: According to the documentation it is required.

Comment: @RyanB. - each view controller has a lifecycle. and each part of the lifecycle does various things you probably don't notice (i.e. instantiate the view, etc). when you don't call `super` on some of the methods, you're making the view controller skip some of it's usual lifecycle, which means other things can break.

Answer (score 1):

Do not add the observer in `viewDidAppear`. Do it in `viewDidLoad`. `viewDidAppear` is potentially called multiple times, which means you might register for the `UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshot` notification multiple times.

Also, you do not need to unregister (`removeObserver`) in iOS9+. And if you're running on a version of iOS less than 9, I would suggest unregistering in `deinit` rather than `viewDidDisappear`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()    

    let mainQueue = OperationQueue.main
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshot, 
                object: nil, 
                queue: mainQueue) { notification in
        print("SCREENSHOT TAKEN")
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but when I leave the screen, the listener is still attached, I only want it on one view controller.

Comment: Add the notification observer in `viewDidLoad` in just the *one* view controller that you want it in.

Comment: Ok, but when I go to a new tab on the app and take a screenshot, it still gets notified

Comment: what are you trying to do? only call this code if you're on a selected tab?

Comment: Really, only on one view controller. I have Tab -> Viewcontroller1 -> viewcontroller2 -> Viewcontroller3. and I only want it called on viewcontroller3, Currently it gets called on every view controller once I open it

Comment: are you registering for the notification in all of the view controllers?

Comment: Only on  calling on viewcontroller3.

Comment: just because you go to another tab, doesn't mean viewController3 no longer exists, so of course it will continue to get called. if you want to avoid the notification from happening while viewController3 is not in view, I would suggest adding the notification in the tab bar itself and in the block check to see what tab you're on and don't execute the code if you're on viewcontroller3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165450/discussion-between-ryan-b-and-jake).

Answer (score 1):

You can store the observer in a private variable and then remove it in your method like:

```
private var screenshotObserver: Any?

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    if screenshotObserver == nil {
        let mainQueue = OperationQueue.main
        screenshotObserver = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshot, object: nil, queue: mainQueue) { notification in
            print("SCREENSHOT TAKEN")
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

    if screenshotObserver != nil {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(screenshotObserver)
        screenshotObserver = nil
    }
}
```